# How to require custom JS files in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm currently trying Rails 6.0.0.rc1 which seems to have moved the default `javascript` folder from `app/assets/javascript` to `app/javascript`. The `application.js` file is now located in `app/javascript/packs`. Now, I want to add a couple of js files, but for some reason they don't get imported and I can't find any documentation on how this can be done in Rails 6. I tried a couple of things:

1. Create a new folder `custom_js` under `app/javascript/packs`, putting all my js files there and then add a `require "custom_js"` to `application.js`.
2. Copy all my js files under `app/javascript/channels` (which should be included by default, since `application.js` has `require("channels")`).
3. Adding `require_tree .` to `application.js`, which was the previous approach.

How can I load my own js files inside a Rails 6 application?

Comment: webpacker replaces the asset-pipeline in rails 6. i would advise to migrate to webpacker before upgrading to rails 6.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Get better-organized code and avoid multiple javascript_pack_tags in your application.html.erb file with this approach:

1. Add your custom `example.js` javascript file to `app/javascript/packs`.
2. Add `require("packs/example")` to your `application.js` file.

---

*I would have liked to add a comment to Asim Hashmi's correct answer. But I don't have enough reputation, so I'll add my suggestion as an answer instead.*

It isn't necessary to include the ".js" extension inside of the require.

Comment: How to specific js file for each controller actions?

Comment: For example: user/index.js, user/show.js, user/form.js

Comment: Is there a way to avoid having to add all the files by name?  Like the whole folder?

Answer (score 25):

You need to do the following steps to add custom javascript file to rails 6 (webpacker)

**1**.Create your custom file named `custom.js` in  `app/javascript/packs` directory.

For testing purpose, write any `console.log` in it.

```
// app/javascript/packs/custom.js

console.log("custom js file loaded")
```

**2**. Go to your `application.html.erb` and add the following line at the end of your `<head></head>`

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'custom', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

**3**. Now execute `rake assets:precompile`
This will pack your javascript code (including our custom file we just added)

Now reload your page and you should see the message

```
custom js file loaded
```

In your browser console.

Answer (score 1):

My custom js has functions which will be called by embedded javascript of serveral html pages. Following snippet works in Rails6, compiled by webpacker:

1. put custom js file in folder **app/javascript/packs** e.g. app/javascript/packs/my_functions.js

```js
say_hello = function(a_text){ 
    console.log("HELLO "+ a_text);  
}
```

2. add **javascript_pack_tag** in html file, e.g. index.html.erb .

```html
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'my_functions' %>
<!-- html here -->

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    say_hello('ABer')
});
</script>
```

Note : This line is inside html body, not in head

```html
<script src="/packs/js/my_functions-1db66368ebbd2fe31abd.js"></script>
```