# How to access custom javascript functions via browser-console in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

For the sake of debugging the javascript-part of a **Rails 6** (version 6.0.0.rc1) web application I want to use my custom javascript functions also in the Chrome console (aka. Inspect).

Back when I used just static HTML files to build a website (as opposed to using a web-framework like Rails as of right now) you would simply embed the JS file in the DOM like this

```
<!-- custom JS -->
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

and could instantly access and execute all custom functions that were placed in this file.

**Background:**
The JS file is placed at the correct rails 6 specific directory as provided in this article: [How to require custom JS files in Rails 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56242664/how-to-require-custom-js-files-in-rails-6)

**Note:**
The rails 6 application also uses the JS file already, since the browser shows the console log message.

Here is the full content of the JS file:

```
// app/javascript/packs/custom.js
console.log("loaded custom.js successfully")

function sayHello () {
  console.log("Hello good Sir or Madam!")
}
```

**Expectation:** I am expecting to open the browser's (Chrome) console and be able to use the sayHello() function in the console.

However, when I do so, I get an error message in the console stating:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: sayHello is not defined
```

Comment: you can add your function to `window` temporarily for debugging

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
sayHello = ()=>{
console.log("Hello good Sir or Madam!");
}
```

then you can evoke in console:

```
>sayHello();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation of why this works and the question code doesn't [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.