# Rails 6 - require JS files in some controller actions

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm currently trying Rails 6.0.0 which seems to have moved the default `javascript` folder from `app/assets/javascript` to `app/javascript`. The `application.js` file is now located in `app/javascript/packs`.

Now, I want to add JS file for each controller action. For example I have:

- `UsersController#index`
- `UsersController#show`
- `UsersController#edit`

On some controller action I need to add some javascript:

- `app/javascript/user/index.js`
- `app/javascript/user/show.js`
- `app/javascript/user/edit.js`
- `app/javascript/user/form.js` (assume in form I need some js tweak)

Here is what I'm currently doing. In controller view:

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'user/index', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

However, in `index.js` I can't call libraries which has been required in `application.js`. For example in application.js:

```
require("bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap")
```

In index.js I call bootstrap specific JS for popover, modal ... I got:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function
```

I don't want to write all JS in application.js because every page have to load entire website JS which is nut! That why I want to split them and include when I need.

Beside, why we have to require JS file in `application.js`? If we using `javascript_pack_tag` do we need to require those file in `application.js`?

Here is a [dummy](https://github.com/truongnmt/dummy/blob/master/config/webpack/environment.js) repo I just created.

Ref: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56242664/how-to-require-custom-js-files-in-rails-6) explain how to require a custom JS file.

Comment: I can't mark as duplicate but this has been answered before here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56242664/how-to-require-custom-js-files-in-rails-6

Comment: What's your criteria to include the `app/javascript/user/form.js` pack?

Comment: @Gotenks-J thanks but I read from that post before I post this question, lemme update a ref link

Comment: @SebastianPalma some validation on client side I guess

Answer (score 0):

Add to your `application.html.erb`:

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag controller_name %> for controllers <br/>
<%= javascript_pack_tag action_name %> for actions
```

Comment: As I updated in question, I got error. I can't call bootstrap method in another script

Answer (score 0):

You can create a folder structure as your view. So say you have some custom form validations you want to add inside the edit view of the user. You have the following structure: `app/views/users/edit.html.erb`

In your `edit.html.erb`, remove all your JS code and remove the script tags. Instead add:

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag('user/edit') %>
```

Open `app/javascript/packs` folder. Create the same folder structure as your edit view like this: `app/javascript/packs/product/edit.js`.

Inside `edit.js`

```
window.onload = function () {
  // Your custom form validation JS code for users/edit
}
```

Open `config/application.rb`, and inside the module:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['user/edit.js']
# Keep appending more assets as you wish.
```